# How to update model's field Django from form with save method?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to update an model's fields with [save method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method):

**forms.py:**

```
class FooForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        exclude = ['created']
```

**views.py:**

```
class FooView(FormView):
    success_url = '/some/url/'
    template_name = 'some/template.html'
    form_class = FooForm
    model = Foo

    def form_valid(self, form):
        if 'foo' in self.request.session:
            pk = self.request.session['foo']
            foo = Foo.objects.get(pk=pk)
            self.object = form.save(instance=foo)
        else:
            self.object = form.save()
            self.request.session['foo'] = self.object.pk
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

I have an error, when i try to use form.save(instance=foo):

```
TypeError at /some/url
save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance'
```

What is my problem?

**Django 1.9.0**

**Python 3.4.3**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the very documentation that you linked, you will see that the `instance` keyword is an input to the ModelForm constructor and not the save method.

You will need to do something like

```
form = FooForm(instance=foo)
form.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should provide an instance to the constructor of the form, not to `save` method.
To make it works, you should use [UpdateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView).

Answer (score 0):

```
def form_valid(self, form):
        if 'foo' in self.request.session:
            pk = self.request.session['foo']
            foo = Foo.objects.get(pk=pk)
            foo_form = self.form_class(form.cleaned_data, instance=foo)
            foo_form.save()
```